# Storyboard UI elements are gray and invisible

Tags: xcode, storyboard

The elements of the storyboard are displaying like the following image:

[image: gray storyboard]

I tried reopen Xcode, I have reinstalled Xcode again and clean Derived data and not success.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is love, Xcode is life.

Just restarted the **computer** and worked again. How else is going to be solved?...

[image]